# agent controller does not see agents

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-tptp

I have setup linux agent controller and it seems working. I am able to connect to it from eclipse. However agent list is empty even when I start jvm which I want to profile.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-agentpath:/<path_to_agent>/agntctrl.linux_em64t-TPTP-4.7.2/plugins/org.eclipse.tptp.javaprofiler/libJPIBootLoader.so=JPIAgent:server=standalone,filters=/<path_to_filters>/classFilter.txt;CGProf $JAVA_OPTS"
```

this is agent settings. Jvm starts successfully but when I click refresh in agent screen in eclipse it is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed server type from `standalone` to `enabled` and it worked!